# Scheme Inverting values

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to convert #t to #f, #f to #t and a negative number to a positive and the opposite.

```
(define inverse
  (lambda (x)
    (cond ((eq? x #t) #f)
          ((eq? x #f) #t)
          (else - x))))
```

It works for the boolean but not the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(else - x)` is not a valid form. Change it to `(else (- x))`.

Btw, you can go without `cond`:

```
(define (inverse x) (if (boolean? x) (not x) (- x)))
```